# Use cases for BMC and BMT in EJB 3.1

Tags: ejb-3.1

I am analyzing the possible use cases in which Bean Managed Transactions(BMT) and Bean Managed Concurrency(BMC) can be used.  Following is the result of my ground work on BMT,

1. **Transactions that may run for an unpredictable time**

   - Container imposes a timeout (eventhough it is configurable) on transactions.
   - For some transactions (eg. FTPing files over to a third party vendor, persisting the results of a jms queue distribution, or committing across two different data sources), transaction times can be quite unpredictable.
   - In such cases, Bean Provider may take control over Transaction management using BMT.
   - Sticking on to CMT in such cases might result in a lot of exceptions and transaction failures.
2. **Multiple transactions within a single bean method**

   - CMT allows only a single transaction for a bean method.
   - In case, we need to use many transactions, we must use BMT - ofcourse it may be possible, in most cases, to have a work around in CMT.  But workaround may not be optimal sometimes.
3. **Single transaction that spans multiple EJB method calls**

   - If multiple methods must be called with the scope of the same transaction, BMT can be used.

How ever, I have not found any interesting use case for BMC.  Only information I was able get is from Enterprise JavaBeans 3.1(6th edition), which says

" ... container-managed concurrency does not cover the full breadth of concerns that multithreaded code must address. In these cases the specification makes available the full power of the Java language’s concurrent tools by offering a bean-managed concurrency mode."

It will be really nice if you could share your experiences on specific use cases where you have used BMT or BMC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BMT is also useful if you want to begin/commit transactions multiple times from within the same bean method.  It's also useful if you want precise control over exceptions thrown during beforeCompletion; for example, JPA optimistic locking can throw an exception during commit that can only be handled from within the EJB if you're using BMT.

BMC is useful if your methods are delegating to another service that already handles concurrency.  For example, if you have a singleton that is managing data using a ConcurrentHashMap, then you don't need the container to perform additional synchronization.